# I need to redirect to a third party auth service if the "request.session" does not have the session variable the auth service sets

Tags: python, django, session, redirect

I have to redirect the page to a third party auth service if the session variables doesn't contain the variable set by this service. This is being done in django admin.

I created a django middleware where I check if the session variable has the desired key. If not, I redirect to the url of the auth service which is present as an app in my django ecosystem. This results in a redirect loop.

How can this be solved?

Sample Code: my_thirdparty_auth_app/middleware.py

```
def process_request(self, request):
    if 3rdparty_authenticated(request):
        print 'AUTHENTICATED ...'
    else:
        print "NOT AUTHENTICATED ..."
        redirect_url = '/test/3rdparty_login/'
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Sample Code: Check myapp/views.py

```
def 3rdparty_authenticated(request):
    """
    Return True if a session shows the user has authenticated
    """
    print "in authenticated() ....."
    if request.session.get('3rdparty_authenticated') == request.user.username:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Can you paste your code here?

Comment: @nikhiln Please see the code added